# How much cash do I need when entering Germany?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, germany, money

How much currency am I required to have on my person when entering Germany, and do I need to exchange it before traveling?

Answer (score 5):

> How much currency am I required to have on my person when entering Germany?

As much as you need to cover your expenses for the duration and type of your trip.  As a general guide, this is approximately 45 EUR / day and a return ticket.

You only need to worry about this is if you are specifically asked for funds.

If you are carrying more than 10,000 EUR in any combination of currency, you have to declare it to customs - otherwise, if caught, you risk having the entire amount confiscated.

> and do I need to exchange it before traveling?

No;  you can show any currency *equivalent* at the immigration counter - again, if asked to do so. Otherwise you can exchange it in Germany or simply use your credit / debit cards depending on what works best for you.

Comment: Can you please provide a source for the 45€/day? Is this some kind of regulation?

Answer (score 1):

If that question is asked, you need to convince the border officials that you can pay for your livelihood. This can be done with approx. €45/day in cash, but also by credit cards, by prepaid room and board, and by other means.